Type Error in .d.ts File Angular Component from Library
I have created a library in Angular, and within it I have created a component. After running npm i, I receive an error in the .d.ts file:

Error:
node_modules/@my-lib/recursive-tree/lib/recursive-tree.component.d.ts:24:5 - error TS2344: Type '{ nodes: { alias: "nodes"; required: true; }; orderedChildren: { alias: "orderedChildren"; required: true; };
position: { alias: "position"; required: false; }; currentPosition: {
alias: "currentPosition"; required: true; }; ids: { ...; };
disableItem: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key:
string]: string; }'.   Property '"nodes"' is incompatible with index
signature.
Type '{ alias: "nodes"; required: true; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

This is my recursive-tree.component.ts:
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-recursive-tree[currentPosition]',
  templateUrl: 'recursive-tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['recursive-tree.component.scss']
})
export class RecursiveTreeComponent {

  @Input() nodes?: any[];
  @Input() orderedChildren: string[] = [];
  @Input() position: number = 0;
  @Input() currentPosition!: string;
  @Input() ids?: { [key: string]: string[] };
  @Input() disableItem: boolean = false;
  @Output() selectedIdsChange = new EventEmitter<{ [key: string]: string[] }>();

  constructor() { }

  trackById(index: number, item: any) {
    return item.id;
  }

  updateSelectedIds(node: any) {

    if (!this.ids) {
        this.ids = {};
    }

    if (!this.ids[this.currentPosition]) {
        this.ids[this.currentPosition] = [];
    }
    
    if (node.selected) {
      if (!this.ids[this.currentPosition].includes(node.id)) {
        this.ids[this.currentPosition].push(node.id);
        this.deselectChildNodes(node);
      }
    } else {
      this.ids[this.currentPosition] = this.ids[this.currentPosition].filter(id => id !== node.id);
    }

    this.selectedIdsChange.emit(this.ids)
  }

  
  deselectChildNodes(node: any, pos: number = this.position) {
    const childNodes = node[this.orderedChildren[pos]];
    if (childNodes && Array.isArray(childNodes)) {
      for (const child of childNodes) {
        child.selected = false;
        const childPos = this.orderedChildren[pos + 1];
        if (this.ids && this.ids[childPos]) {
          this.ids[childPos] = this.ids[childPos].filter(id => id !== child.id);
        }
        this.deselectChildNodes(child, pos + 1);
      }
    }
  }


  updateSelectedIdsChild( obj: {[key:string]: string[]}){

    if (!this.ids) {
      this.ids = {};
    }

    this.ids = {...this.ids,
      ...obj
    }

    this.selectedIdsChange.emit(this.ids)

  }

}


I tried to search for solutions online but I found nothing.
